# Updating data in Kepler Maps addDataToMap

Tags: javascript, python, html, kepler.gl

I've saved the Kepler map that I created and customized using Python as an HTML file (populated with some default data). I needed to update data in the map on an event and thus I'm updating data in __KeplerDataConfig using an API on the occurrence of that event. Could someone please help me with calling addDataToMap function to refresh the map component so that it reads the updated __KeplerDataConfig (with updated data) and thus the updates the data reflected on the map. I couldn't find any method to call addDataToMap on the updated config/data or any other way to reload the map component only instead of reloading entire html page.

Thanks!